# Vue on click event returns Can't find variable error on mobile only

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have some weird issue that is happening only on mobile. I just plugged in my phone and looked over what it has to say. It seems that my click event is causing the issue.

I have ComponentA and ComponentB. ComponentB has click event that emits with value:

```
<tr v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" @click="$emit('onItemClick', item)"></tr>
```

This is the ComponentA that catches the event:

```
<ItemList @onItemClick="didClickItem" />
```

Now on mobile only I get the following error(note that I can't find variable named Notification anywhere, I looked over the project).

> Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: Can't find variable:
>   Notification"

I have no clue what to do or how to debug further. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using firebase by chance or something that would require web notifications?

Comment: @StevenB. I do. Can you tell me why you ask? :D

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41493866/firebase-on-ipads-safari-cant-find-variable-notification)